# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver not found in Worklight platform or project

Tags: java, db2, ibm-mobilefirst

I try to test an sql adapter that connects to db2 but I get the following result:

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver not found in Worklight platform or project

here is my code:

```
<dataSourceDefinition>
    <driverClass>com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver</driverClass>
    <url>jdbc:db2://localhost:50000/WLTEST</url>
    <user>db2admin</user>
    <password>db2admin</password> 
</dataSourceDefinition>
```

any idea what is going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean that your Worklight database is DB2-based? If yes,

- make sure to also edit worklight.properties with the correct DB2 setup

Also make sure that:

- the DB2 connector driver exists in the server\lib folder

Comment: Thank you, I added the DB2connector into the server\lib and it worked

Answer (score 9):

Add the two jars:

> db2jcc.jar
>   db2jcc_license_cu.jar

Add them to the libraries `jar` folder.

Comment: add a link to where to get them and i'll be forever thankful

Comment: found [this one](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=4020&uid=swg21385217)