# Runtime: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class jdbc:db2:\/\/localhost:50000\/

Tags: db2, ibm-mobilefirst, procedure, invoke

Saw this post
[java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver not found in Worklight platform or project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19128792/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-class-com-ibm-db2-jcc-db2driver-not-found-in-w)

db2jcc.jar and db2jcc_license_cu.jar are present in server/lib.
One test project I made few days ago that one is running good.
but today went I applied same method in my final project gives error.
Even tried to create another new project to test but still gives error.

Parameters:
'hello','123'

```
{
"errors": [
   "Runtime: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class   jdbc:db2:\/\/localhost:50000\/YummyDB2 not found in Worklight bundles."
 ],
   "info": [
  ],
   "isSuccessful": false,
"warnings": [
]
}
```

SQL_ADAPTER_INSERT_REGISTERACC_2.xml,some portion

```
            <driverClass>
                jdbc:db2://localhost:50000/YummyDB2
            </driverClass>
            <url>com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver</url>
            <user>abc</user>
            <password>123</password>
```

SQL_ADAPTER_INSERT_REGISTERACC_2-impl.js

```
    var procedure1Statement = WL.Server.createSQLStatement("insert into YummyTable2 values(?,?)");
    function procedure1(param,param1) {
    return WL.Server.invokeSQLStatement({
    preparedStatement : procedure1Statement,
    parameters : [param,param1]
});
}

function procedure2(param) {
return WL.Server.invokeSQLStoredProcedure({
    procedure : "storedProcedure2",
    parameters : [param]
});
}
```

Comment: You mixed up the driver class name and the database URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the question you've linked to. The `connectionPolicy` node in the adapter XML file is incorrect set.

I believe it should look like this:

```
...
...
<driverClass>com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver</driverClass>
<url>jdbc:db2://localhost:50000/YummyDB2</url>
<user>abc</user>
<password>123</password>
```